# sqlalchemy: can't get any data from database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm learning how to use sqlalchemy and pyramid so I've been trying to get my objects from the database that's already created but I can't get anything. I read the documentation of sqlalchemy but I can't get any objects.

models.py

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Poll(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'poll'
    # Here we define columns for the table person
    # Notice that each column is also a normal Python instance attribute.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'type'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250))

class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'question'
    # Here we define columns for the table address.
    # Notice that each column is also a normal Python instance attribute.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(250))
    type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('type.id'))
    type = relationship(Type)
    poll_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('poll.id'))
    poll = relationship(Poll)

class Option(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'option'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(250))
    question_id =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey('question.id'))
    question = relationship(Question)

class Answer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'answer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(250))
    option_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('option.id'))
    option = relationship(Option)
```

views.py

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from .models import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

db = create_engine('mysql://polls:polls@localhost:3306/polls')
db.echo = True
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Session()

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.jinja2')
def my_view(request):
    q = session.query(Poll).first()
    return {'project': 'polls', 'variable':q.name}
```

template

```
{% extends "layout.jinja2" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content">
  <h1><span class="font-semi-bold">Pyramid</span> <span class="smaller">Starter project</span></h1>
  <p class="lead">Welcome to <span class="font-normal">{{variable}}</span>, a&nbsp;Pyramid application generated&nbsp;by<br><span class="font-normal">Cookiecutter</span>.</p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I get a None object in the view. What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: did you insert some test records into the `poll` table first?

Comment: Yes, I have a few rows inserted in poll.

Comment: awesome, what do you get if you use sqlalchemy to query the database interactively from the terminal

Comment: I get attempted related import when importing models

Comment: that's a bit tricky to solve, might not work in 1st try: replace `from .models import *` with `from models import *` in all files, then from your working directory, launch the python interpreter, import `session` from `views` & try to run these lines `q = session.query(Poll).first()`, then `print(q.name)`. if you see data, then you can rule out db connection as a source of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a little bit confused with concepts but apparently the problem was that I hide Base.metadata.create_all(engine) in models.py thinking that it would force to recreate all the database. It looks like if this is not available sqlalchemy doesn't map the data correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQLAlchemy documentation, it says the proper way to connect to a MySQL DB is like so:

```
db = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://polls@localhost:3306/polls'
```

You could give that a shot ( adding in the `+pymysql` ) when you call `create_engine()`

Note: you may have to install pymysql with `pip install pymysql`

Comment: What did you read? I read this one and has a lot of options http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html?highlight=mysql#mysql I tried that anyway and +mysqldb with no differences

Comment: @ffuentes if you go here [http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql) this is where I initially got the info.